# How to pass // or " into a macro substitution

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

I was trying to know how `//` and `"` can be passed into a macro substitution as like below:

```
#define STR(str) #str
```

while invoking `STR(hel"lo)` or `STR(hel//lo)`.
This gives error. Is there any way to pass these into a macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to pass `//` into a macro invocation except embedded in a string or character constant as the `//` marks the start of a comment-to-end-of-line.  Comment stripping is done before macros are processed.

Similarly, there is no way to pass a naked double quote to a macro.  The double quote is either inside a character constant or marks the start of a string.

Similarly for `/*` and `'`, with appropriate changes to the reasoning.

Comment: With gcc at least, you can pass `//` to a macro invocation when compiling with `-std=c89`. If it's stringized, it even can result in a valid token (`STR(hel//lo)` from above results in `"hel//lo"`).

Comment: I was discussing the current and previous versions of the standard; not the 23-year-old version of the standard.  However, you're correct that a strict C-only C89 compiler will allow you have `//` passed to the preprocessor, formally as two pp-tokens, logically separated by a space (because `//` is not a symbol in C89).

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to pass them in as you wrote it.  Translation phase 3 is "The source file is decomposed into preprocessing tokens and sequences of white space including comments".

That means the STR(hel//lo) is turned into STR(hel (with a trailing space instead of the comment).

"The categories of preprocessing tokens are header names, identifiers, pp-numbers, character constants, stringl literals, punctuators, and single non-white space characters that do not lexically match the other preprocessing token characters.  If a ' or " character matches the last character, the behaviour is undefined" ... which means STR(hel"lo) is not allowed either.

Answer (score 0):

Given an identity macro and an evaluating stringize macro,

```
#define ID(X) X
#define STR_EVAL(X) STR(X)
```

You can "escape" one slash

```
STR_EVAL( ID(hel)ID(/)/lo )
```

As for the single quote, sorry, you're out of luck. The arguments to a macro must be tokens, and a single quote is specifically forbidden from being a token.